# Computing the decimation ratio between two m-sequences

Tags: finite-fields, coding-theory

Let's suppose I have an [LFSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register) that generates an m-sequence $y_1[k]$ --- in other words, the LFSR has $N$ bits and $y_1[k]$ has period $m=2^N - 1$.

Now suppose I know someone has decimated this and taken every $j$th element, so $y_2[k] = y_1[jk+b]$. And I know the $y_2[k]$ but the values of $j$ and $b$ are unknown.

Is there any efficient way to compute the decimation ratio $j$ without testing all possible values of $j$?

(Note 1: if $b$ is unknown then there are $N$ possible solutions for $j$ because $2j, 4j, 8j, \ldots\, j^{2^{N-1}}$ can have sequences generated by LFSRs with the same coefficients, differing only by a time shift. I have no idea if the problem is easier to solve for known $b$.)

(Note 2: This smells vaguely like a discrete logarithm problem but I cannot figure out how to restate it as such. I will be satisfied if I can obtain an equivalent discrete logarithm problem, because the values of $N$ that I deal with are small enough that I can use established techniques like [Pollard's rho and kangaroo algorithms](https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/1093.php) to compute the value of $j$.)

---

There are several equivalent ways of stating this problem (I posted one on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2480132/determining-decimation-ratio-given-characteristic-polynomials-of-quotient-rings):

- $y_1[k] = \operatorname{Tr}_{F_1}(w_1x^k)$ where $F_1 = GF(2)[x]/p_1(x)$ and similarly for $y_2[k], F_2, w_2, p_2(x)$; the traces are related (because of the decimation ratio $j$) by $\operatorname{Tr}_{F_1}(w_1x^{jk+b}) = \operatorname{Tr}_{F_2}(w_2x^k)$; the coefficients of $p_1(x)$ are the LFSR coefficients; $p_2(x)$ can be determined from the [Berlekamp-Massey algorithm](https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/1099.php), and $w_1$ and $w_2$ can be determined from state recovery methods by running the LFSR backwards (I have a blog article in progress on this but it's unfinished and not a quick thing to summarize, sorry)
- $p_1(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $x$ in $F_1 = GF(2)[x]/p_1(x)$; $p_2(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $x^j$ in $F_1$ and $p_2(x)$ is also the minimal polynomial of $x$ in $F_2 = GF(2)[x]/p_2(x)$; given $p_1(x)$ and $p_2(x)$, what is $j$?

---

Example:

- $p_1(x) = x^9 + x^4 + 1$
- $y_1[0..18] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]$
- $j = 107, b = 80$
- $y_2[0..18] = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]$

We can use Berlekamp-Massey on the $y_2$ values to determine $p_2(x) = x^9+x^7+x^5+x+1$, and state recovery techniques to determine that $y_2[k] = HB(v_2x^k)$ with $v_2 = x^8 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3$ (equivalently the LFSR has initial state `101111000`), where $HB(u)$ is the high bit = coefficient of $x^8$.

But I'm stuck on how to get from there to $j=107$ or other members of its cyclotomic coset $\{107, 214, 428, 345, 179, 358, 205, 410, 309\}$, aside from checking every value of $j$ --- or at least, the smallest coset representative of every value of $j$, and then using Berlekamp-Massey until I get a match of $p_2(x)$.

Comment: posted here after no luck on [dsp.stackexchange.com](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/44920/computing-the-decimation-ratio-between-two-m-sequences) or [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2480132/determining-decimation-ratio-given-characteristic-polynomials-of-quotient-rings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, $p_2$ has $x^j$ as a zero in $F_1$. In other words, $p_1(x)$ divides $p_2(x^j)$ over $\mathrm{GF}(2)$.

To find $j$ from the given $p_1$ and $p_2$, one can factor $p_2(y)$ in $F_1[y]$, and for every zero $y_0\in F_1$ of $p_2(y)$, find the discrete log of $y_0$ base $x$ in $F_1$.

Here is a sample [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) code that recovers values of $j$ in the given example:

```
? X = ffgen((x^9+x^4+1)*Mod(1,2));  \\ x as an element of F1
? lf = select(t->poldegree(t,x)==1, factorff(x^9+x^7+x^5+x+1,2,y^9+y^4+1)[,1] ); \\ linear factors of p(y)
? for(i=1,#lf, z = lift( -polcoeff(lf[i],0)/polcoeff(lf[i],1) ); print( fflog(subst(z,y,X),X) ) )
214
345
309
358
428
205
410
179
107
```

Notice that $p_1$ and $p_2$ alone do not uniquely define $j$ (e.g., in the example above there is an extraneous value $179$), but together with initial terms of the decimated sequence they do.

Comment: dumb question, what's $F_1$? is that the infinite set of integers? I'm familiar with the notation $F_{q^n}$ for finite fields.

Comment: @JasonS: You defined $F_1$ in your question.

Comment: Everything else looks promising -- I have to check my mental model of all this to make sure I understand all the pieces but I'm familiar with polynomial factoring techniques so I think I can translate this to the Python code I work with. Does it work with any value of $j$, or just the ones that are relatively prime to $2^N-1$ where $p_2(x)$ is a primitive polynomial?

Comment: OH -- okay, oops. Haha.

Comment: I guess the thing that confuses me is that $F_1[y]$ is a polynomial ring where the each element is a polynomial with coefficients that are elements of $F_1 = GF(2)[x]/p_1(x)$ which are themselves represented by polynomials.

Comment: $F_1$ is simply a realization of $\mathrm{GF}(2^N)$ in polynomials modulo $p_1$ over $\mathrm{GF}(2)$. So $F_1[y]$ is the ring of polynomials with coefficients from the finite field $\mathrm{GF}(2^N)$.

Comment: I tried running PARI/GP in my browser and following your example with some more `print` statements to see what is going on. How does it know whether to factor with respect to $x$ or to $y$?

Comment: Ugh, how do you factor a polynomial in $F_1[y]$? I like [McEliece's algorithm](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/91b8/d2172d6ceeb99fd548532483aa8f3a99c8e5.pdf) for factoring in $GF(2)[x]$ because it's a product of two gcd's, but if I were to use it in $F_1[y]$ I would have to evaluate gcd for each element in $F_1$ which is not practical with large degree polynomials.

Comment: @JasonS: See https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/html-stable/Arithmetic_functions.html#factorff and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields

Comment: Ok, thanks. Would distinct-degree factorization work well here? I understand that one for the most part; understanding Cantor-Zassenhaus has eluded me.

Comment: oh wait, no, it would be awful because all the factors here are linear, so I need an equal-degree factorization method.

Comment: After some work to understand and implement, Cantor-Zassenhaus worked nicely for me. [This article](http://blog.fkraiem.org/2013/12/01/polynomial-factorisation-over-finite-fields-part-3-final-splitting-cantor-zassenhaus-in-odd-characteristic/) helped (ignore the title, it discusses $GF(2)$ also). Thanks for the suggestion!